# Delta-Epsilon Continuity of a Dirichlet-like function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I'm trying to determine whether the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, &\text{ if $x$ is rational},
\\
1, &\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$ is continuous (everywhere).

I believe that it's not, but only because I employed the sequential characterization of limits method.  When I try an epsilon-delta proof, I can't seem to choose a good epsilon to make it work.  For a similar function where f(x) = 0 for irrationals, I can get a/2 for any irrational a to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any point $a\neq 1$, choose $\varepsilon=|a-1|/2$. This ought to work. The reason you can't do it at $1$ is that this function is actually continuous at $x=1$. This idea also works for the case $f(x)=0$ for irrationals because then $\varepsilon=|a-0|/2$ works, as you pointed out.